Share Buttons Don't Take In Content
I am trying to create a share-button bar, but none of them work:
Whatsapp: Shares the text and link, but the link doesn't appear in blue nor getting a preview. I care about the link being clickable.
Facebook and Twitter: Nothing gets suggested. The post box is opened but nothing is pre-written.
Twitter: Getting plaintext share with a lot of %20.
I tried with addtoany and without it, but failed.
How to correctly create simple share buttons?
import React from 'react';
import { FaFacebook, FaTwitter, FaLinkedin, FaWhatsapp } from 'react-icons/fa';

const ShareButtons = () => {
    const urlToShare = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
    const textToShare = encodeURIComponent("Some Text");

    const iconSize = 25;

    const shareOnFacebook = () => {
        const fbUrl = `https://www.addtoany.com/add_to/facebook?linkurl=${urlToShare}&linkname=${textToShare}`;
        window.open(fbUrl, '_blank');
    };

    const shareOnTwitter = () => {
        const twitterUrl = `https://twitter.com/share?url=${encodeURIComponent(urlToShare)}&text=${encodeURIComponent(textToShare)}`;
        window.open(twitterUrl, '_blank');
    };

    const shareOnLinkedIn = () => {
        const linkedInUrl = `https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=${encodeURIComponent(urlToShare)}&title=${encodeURIComponent(textToShare)}`;
        window.open(linkedInUrl, '_blank');
    };

    const shareOnWhatsApp = () => {
        const whatsappUrl = `https://www.addtoany.com/add_to/whatsapp?linkurl=${urlToShare}&linkname=${textToShare}`;
        window.open(whatsappUrl, '_blank');
    };

    return (
        <div className="shareButtons">
            <button onClick={shareOnFacebook}>
                <FaFacebook size={iconSize} />
            </button>
            <button onClick={shareOnTwitter}>
                <FaTwitter size={iconSize} />
            </button>
            <button onClick={shareOnLinkedIn}>
                <FaLinkedin size={iconSize} />
            </button>
            <button onClick={shareOnWhatsApp}>
                <FaWhatsapp size={iconSize} />
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ShareButtons;


So you had some issues with the LinkedIn share API, but the main issue is the link has to be accessible on the web and do not encode the text for Twitter


"use client";

import React from "react";
import { FaFacebook, FaTwitter, FaLinkedin, FaWhatsapp } from "react-icons/fa";

const ShareButtons = () => {
  const currentUrl = encodeURIComponent("https://www.google.com");
  const message = encodeURIComponent("Check out this content!");

  const iconSize = 25;

  const shareOnFacebook = () => {
    const fbUrl = `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${currentUrl}`;
    window.open(fbUrl, "_blank", "noopener,noreferrer");
  };

  const shareOnTwitter = () => {
    const twitterUrl = `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=${currentUrl}&text=${message}`;
    window.open(twitterUrl, "_blank", "noopener,noreferrer");
  };

  const shareOnLinkedIn = () => {
    const linkedInUrl = `https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=${currentUrl}&title=${message}&summary=${message}&source=${encodeURIComponent(
      "YourWebsiteName"
    )}`;
    window.open(linkedInUrl, "_blank", "noopener,noreferrer");
  };

  const shareOnWhatsApp = () => {
    const whatsappUrl = `https://wa.me/?text=${message}%20${currentUrl}`;
    window.open(whatsappUrl, "_blank", "noopener,noreferrer");
  };

  return (
    <div className="share-buttons">
      <button onClick={shareOnFacebook} aria-label="Share on Facebook">
        <FaFacebook size={iconSize} />
      </button>
      <button onClick={shareOnTwitter} aria-label="Share on Twitter">
        <FaTwitter size={iconSize} />
      </button>
      <button onClick={shareOnLinkedIn} aria-label="Share on LinkedIn">
        <FaLinkedin size={iconSize} />
      </button>
      <button onClick={shareOnWhatsApp} aria-label="Share on WhatsApp">
        <FaWhatsapp size={iconSize} />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ShareButtons;




Thanks
It all works, except for linkedin, which deletes anything after the domain. And / or query after the domain is erased. I need the full address
